# C# check if SQL query is only for creating view

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I would like to add an option that user using web ui can define some views in our product.

We let super admins put in SQL query that would create that view.

Do you know if there are any tools for parsing SQL Query and check if it is valid SQL Query for only creating view?

Comment: You could probably just implement this yourself. It seems a bit too specific for a preexisting tool, at least one that I'm aware of. However, since implementing this yourself seems highly error-prone, I would just create a SQL user with only the permission for creating views. Then, in your application where you are adding this feature, ensure that the restricted SQL user is the one that is used for the query.

Comment: TBH, i'd argue with management against this feature, and instead offer some GUI tool to the customer where you can represent the schema and allow them to drag columns and formulae in. If you do end up doing it, at the very least do what @CaitLANJenner suggested and lockdown this to a particular user with a limited permission set.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the input is secure, so your superusers are not going to try to inject stuff ;-)

Anyway the comment above is correct, at least you should check for semicolon and comments. Also that the string starts with "SELECT "

The easiest way - after this basic checks - would be to let them insert the SELECT-Query alone and test it on your connections. Then catch any exception and display it to the superuser.

In case of success, you could even display some of the result, in order give them the possibility to validate the query.

After that you prefix in your code the SELECT with "CREATE VIEW AS " in order to create the view on your database.

Comment: Not all queries begin with select...  CTEs jump to the forefront of my mind.  That may be the only example, but it's a common one.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create a unique role that has select access on every table in the database but nothing else.  Then have your C# run the query as that user in a try/catch block.  This would even eliminate the possibility of SQL injection and/or provide a failsafe for well meaning but careless users.

The main disadvantage I see is that you would need to continually update permissions to ensure that the user is granted select access to new objects, but I think you can define those types of cascading permissions at the schema level...  never tried it at the database level.

Answer (score -1):

Force the query to begin with “`CREATE VIEW`”, e.g. by prefixing whatever is entered with  that string.

Make sure that there is no semicolon inside the query. This will exclude some valid queries (that contain something like “`WHERE a = ';'`” or “`/* comment; */`”), but it is simple and you might get away with it.

Comment: That's why I said to reject strings with a semicolon.

Comment: If the statement contains `GO`, it is syntactically incorrect. Can you give a complete example of what you mean?

Comment: @Stuart: Just execute the query first with a read-only account (and maybe a limitation to 10 records). If it succeeds (and there are no semicolons), prefix it with the  "CREATE VIEW " statement as suggested.

Comment: I don't believe it. Can you prove it?

Comment: I don't get the criticism here...  this is a brilliant answer